# Default \hline after every row

Tags: tables, longtable, hline

I have a long table inside a longtable environment. I don't want to put \hline everywhere. How do I tell LaTeX to do it for me?
I need \hline after every row and also before the first row.

Comment: `\newcommand\n{\\\hline}` then use `\n` instead of `\\ `

Comment: Are you even sure it is a good idea to have a `\hline` after each row? In most cases this looks bad.

Comment: With `tabularray` package it is rather easy to do this.

Comment: tabularray I can't use since it's too new.